# Traverse AVL Tree starting from leaf node

Tags: c++, tree, avl-tree, inorder, postorder

I am looking for a way to traverse an AVL tree from the bottom upwards.

Given a pointer to a leaf in the tree, I need to traverse the tree starting from that leaf.

Any ideas how that is possible? (I have a parent pointer from each node.)

Comment: By _traverse_, do you simply mean follow the path from leaf to root (which seems trivial if the tree nodes have parent pointers) or something else?

Comment: You should show at least the data structure and your best attempt at traversing the tree.  Preferably, you should create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — same thing, different name and explanation.

Comment: By traverse i mean starting from leaf up to the root.